# Position of UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm using a tableview to display a list of rows and when selected, I want additional controls to appear right below the cell, probably in another view which I will control.

So far, I've managed to get a reference to the selected cell by running through the visiblecells array in the tableview but the frame property always returns a y-coordinate of 0 no matter what scroll position the table is in.

How do I get the position of the cell relative to the window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to deal with table views is in their own terms. That is, if you want to position something new inside the table, put it in a cell. It sounds like you want to subclass UITableViewCell to make your controls, and go through the whole tableView beginUpdates - insertCells - endUpdates process to animate their appearance.